# Count two items in a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to define a query that returns item num, item size, item colour and a count of how many items of a given color and size there are. 
I am not able to figure out what kind of count the question is asking.

Here's what I tried but I am getting errors:-

```
SELECT inventoryItem.itemNum, 
       inventoryItem.itemSize, 
       inventoryItem.itemColor, 
       count(inventoryItem.itemSize), 
       count(inventoryItem.itemColor),
FROM inventoryItem
GROUP BY inventoryItem.itemSize, inventoryItem.itemColor;
```

Comment: what error you get? mysql or oracle? choose one.

Comment: Couple things. Is it MySQL or is it Oracle? Also you don't need to keep saying `inventoryItem.` if it is the only table.

Comment: Thanks. It's Oracle.

Comment: isnt clear what result you want. Show us some sample data and expected output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Basically, I want to take a count of how many distinct combinations of a triple of values there are.

Comment: Add itemNum in your Group By or remove ItemNum from your Select

Answer (score 1):

Query you  shown is not going to work, because in select there is column inventoryItem.itemNum, and that column is missing in your group by clause.

You are asked to give counts of items of a given color and size, that can be done using below query. In case you need itemNum, it will have to be added to select and group by section both.

```
 SELECT inventoryItem.itemSize,
        inventoryItem.itemColor, 
        count(1) count
   FROM inventoryItem
GROUP BY inventoryItem.itemSize, inventoryItem.itemColor
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT itemSize, 
   itemColor, 
   count(1) itemcount
FROM inventoryItem
GROUP BY itemSize,
itemColor;
```